# Не получается подмонтировать загрузочный образ диска

Tags: ubuntu, изображения, img, boot

Мне нужно создать образ загрузочной флешки с файловой системой FAT32 (из-под Убунты). Имеется образ бутсектора (`boot.bin`). Создаю образ такими командами:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=fs.img bs=512 count=2880  
mkfs.fat fs.img
dd bs=512 skip=1 if=fs.img of=nbs.img  
cat boot.bin > image.img  
cat nbs.img >> image.img
```

В результате имеются четыре образа:

1. `fs.img` (образ с файловой системой, бутсектор не записан; успешно подключается штатными средствами Ubuntu);
2. `nbs.img` (`fs.img`с отпиленным первым сектором, не подключается);
3. `boot.bin` (образ бутсектора; не подключается по понятным причинам)
4. `image.img` (полный образ с бутсектором и файловой системой; **не подключается**).

Одно мне неясно: почему `image.img` не получается подключить?

Comment: "не получается подключить?" - как подключаете, что в итоге?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов подключаю через sudo mount -t vfat ./image.img /mnt/image, получаю в ответ wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop7...  or other error. В syslog пишется FAT-fs (loop7): bogus number of FAT structure и оттуда же Can't find a valid FAT filesystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

командой `mkfs.fat fs.img` вы создали файловую систему на **всём** объёме «диска».

---

как это происходит «обычно», ну, например, с реальными дисками?

посмотрите на [структуру mbr](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C#.D0.A1.D1.82.D1.80.D1.83.D0.BA.D1.82.D1.83.D1.80.D0.B0_MBR), занимающей (обычно) первый сектор диска: там располагается (помимо кода загрузчика) и таблица разделов (адреса на диске, где начинаются разделы).

дальше посмотрите на [структуру описания раздела](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C#.D0.A1.D1.82.D1.80.D1.83.D0.BA.D1.82.D1.83.D1.80.D0.B0_.D0.BE.D0.BF.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.B0), занимающую (обычно) первый сектор раздела: там располагается информация о том, по какому адресу начинается **содержимое** раздела (обычно содержимым является какая-нибудь файловая система) и по какому заканчиваетя.

---

вышеупомянутой командой вы создали файловую систему не на **содержимом раздела** (ведь вы и не создавали раздел на своём «диске»), а на **всём** «диске».

а после этого заменили первый сектор, занимаемый файловой системой, каким-то «левым» (с точки зрения файловой системы) содержимым.

естественно, этим действием вы «убили» файловую систему. ну, теоретически, восстановить её, конечно, можно — это уже зависит от самой файловой системы — но монтироваться в таком сосотоянии она, конечно, не будет.

Comment: Большое спасибо, не подумал о таблице разделов)